# Concurrency link error when using std::async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, cmake

I have a project with google test framework created with `cmake`. As soon as I am using `std::async`, I am getting link errors. But I have no problems using other stuff from STL. Like `std::thread`, `std::package_task` etc.

The link error I get is that I am missing symbols from:

```
Concurrency::details::_ContextCallback::_Reset(void)"
Concurrency::details::_ContextCallback::_Capture(void)"
Concurrency::details::_ExceptionHolder::ReportUnhandledError(void)
```

I have no problems in other projects using `std::async` in other projects created with cmake. But I can't find out what I´m missing?

I am using VS2017.

The code that fails:

```
std::async([]() {
    return 0;
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a standard class? Perhaps something from google test?

Comment: are you linking to any libraries? Are they all built with the same version of visual studio? Please provide a [mcve]